# SwiftUI: Setting individual colors for .toolbar ToolbarItem?

Tags: swiftui

Generally I like to stick with default color options for accessibility reasons, but I have a specific use case and I am unable to change an individual .toolbar ToolbarItem color.

I can override *all* ToolbarItem colors by using the commented out code at top of my snippet, but I want to color **individual** icons.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
//    init() {
//        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIToolbar.self]).tintColor = .systemRed
//    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .toolbar {
                    
                    // To be colored RED
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Icon One", systemImage: "stop.fill")})
                    }
                    
                    // To be colored BLACK
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Button(action: {}, label: {Label("Icon Two", systemImage: "play.fill")})
                    }
                    
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all standard types (button, image, text, etc) are intercepter by ToolbarItem and converted into appropriate internal representation. But custom view (eg. shape based)... is not. So see below a demo of possible approach.

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
    ShapeButton(shape: Rectangle(), color: .red) {
        print(">> works")
    }
}
```

and simple custom Shape-based button

```
struct ShapeButton<S:Shape>: View {
    var shape: S
    var color: Color
    var action: () -> ()

    @GestureState private var tapped = false
    var body: some View {
        shape
            .fill(color).opacity(tapped ? 0.4 : 1)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 0.15), value: tapped)
            .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .updating($tapped) { value, state, _ in
                    state = true
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    action()
                })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Yep, I've been struggling with the same thing. It looks that `Buttons` are using system tint color and its style overall.

Here is my take:

```
content
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            HStack {
                StyledButton(image: .system("arrow.left")) { ... }
                Spacer(minLength: 0)    // important to not fell button to default styling
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea is to not display Button only, but together with other UI elements. Looks like a SwiftUI bug to me. (Or just trying to out-smart you.)

Comment: Wierd but works like a charm!!, as a note, the issue was only happend on iphone 11 devices, the onTapGesture was not working. We need to use a button instead.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I've found is to ditch `Button` and use `.onTapGesture` instead.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World!")
                .toolbar {
                    
                    // To be colored RED
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Label("Icon One", systemImage: "stop.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                // Respond to tap
                            }
                    }
                    
                    // To be colored BLACK
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Label("Icon One", systemImage: "play.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                // Respond to tap
                            }
                    }
                    
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: ToolbarItem appears to ignore the .onTapGesture. In other words I don't think your solution works. The color correctly changes, but your new "button" doesn't call any action. Also, the Label doesn't dim during the tap like a normal Button would.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop into UIKit it's working for me.

```
struct ButtonRepresentation: UIViewRepresentable {
    let sfSymbolName: String
    let titleColor: UIColor
    let action: () -> ()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
        let b = UIButton()
        let largeConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
        let image = UIImage(systemName: sfSymbolName, withConfiguration: largeConfig)
        b.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        b.tintColor = titleColor
        b.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return b
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(action: action)
    }
    
    typealias UIViewType = UIButton
    
    class Coordinator {
        let action: () -> ()
        
        @objc
        func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.action()
        }
        
        init(action: @escaping () -> ()) {
            self.action = action
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add separate ButtonRepresentations with different colors.

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
        ButtonRepresentation(sfSymbolName: closeIcon, titleColor: closeIconColor) { 
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this trick only works on iOS.

But on the bright side it also works for Menu as well:

```
Menu {
    Button("A title") {}
} label : {
    HStack {
            Label("Star"), systemImage: "star")
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
    }
}
```