# Why doesn't the button's image background show up in toolbar using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In Apple's calendar app, they provide a toolbar item that toggles its style based on some state. It essentially acts as a Toggle. I'm trying to re-create this same thing in SwiftUI and make it work well in both light and dark mode. I was able to make a view that works as intended, until I put it into the toolbar and it no longer shows the selected state. Here is my attempt:

```
struct ToggleButtonView: View {
    @State private var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isOn.toggle()
        }, label: {
            if isOn {
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet.below.rectangle")
                    .accentColor(Color(.systemBackground))
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0)
                                    .fill(Color.accentColor)
                                    .frame(width: 26, height: 26))
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet.below.rectangle")
            }
        })
        .accentColor(.red)
    }
}
```

And here is how I am actually placing the button into the toolbar:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<5) { number in
                    Text("Number \(number)")
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    ToggleButtonView()
                
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Plz halp")
        }
        .accentColor(.red)
    }
}
```

Here are screenshots from the calendar app. Notice the toolbar item to the left of the search icon.

[image: Not highlighted light]
[image: Highlighted light]
[image: Not highlighted dark]
[image: Highlighted dark]

Comment: can you show the code where and how you put it into the toolbar ?

Comment: Yes! The post should be updated.

Comment: works well for me both in light and dark modes, on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst. Maybe it is different on older systems.

Comment: I wasn't expecting that. I'm on macOS 11.4, Xcode 12.5.1, target iOS 14. I even created a new project and copied exactly what I put in this post, and it doesn't show the background when the toggle is on.

Comment: can someone confirm it works on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15.

Comment: I can confirm it works fine on Xcode 13.0 beta (13A5155e), background is set in red

Comment: Looks like this may be an iOS 14 issue?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
            .toolbar {
                // placement as you see fit
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    ToggleButtonView()
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    })
                }
            }
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work either :( thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with how SwiftUI handles ToolbarItems before iOS 15. [According to Asperi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979876/1496143) to a similar question, "...all standards types (button, image, text, etc) are intercepted by ToolbarItem and converted into an appropriate internal representation."

### Toggle buttons in SwiftUI iOS 15

Interestingly enough, iOS 15 now provides a standard solution to the use-case above using the `.button` toggle style, as shown in the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
            Image(systemName: "list.bullet.below.rectangle")
        }
    }
}
```